# What is the Relationship behind these two parametric curves.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$ <x(t),y(t)> = (3cos(t) + cos(3t)),(3sin(t) - sin(3t)) $$
$$ |x|^{2/3} +|y|^{2/3}=4^{2/3} $$
I was messing around in desmos and found this relationship and was wondering if there were any underlying ideas to relate the two .

Comment: Hint: $\cos(3t) = 4\cos^3(t) - 3\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t) = 3\sin(t) - 4\sin^3(t)$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use Sandeep's hint above, which should get you something where $x$ and $y$ are cubics.  Then, use the Pythagorean Theorem ($\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$) to eliminate the trigonometric terms.